# Trying to pass a prop between pages using Link in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

So I have a page with six `Link` tags which all need to redirect to one page with different props depending on which link is clicked. Here's how I'm passing props:

```
      <Link href={{
        pathname: '/products',
        query: {category: 'Starters'}
      }}>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="content-overlay"></div>
            <img class="content-image" src="/starters.png" />
            <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
              <h3 class="content-title text-uppercase">Starters</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3>Starters</h3>
        </div>
      </Link>
```

On the `products` page, here's how I'm reading these props:

```
export default function products(){

    const router = useRouter()
    const {id} = router.query
    console.log(id)
    
    
    return(
        <>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
            <h1 className="text-center">{id}</h1>
        <Footer></Footer>
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem here is that my `id` value is read as undefined or empty. I need to take this value, show it on my page and then send it to an API endpoint which will then use this string to execute a conditional SQL query.

Any idea as to why I'm getting an empty or undefined value and how to fix this?

Comment: You're passing the value as `category` query param, but reading it from `id` query param. Try accessing `router.query.category` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves I've tried that. Doing so gives the following error `Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'router.query.category' as it is undefined.`

Comment: That's not what I meant. Either accessing `const { category } = router.query` or `router.query.category` directly. You're not passing `id` in your query params anywhere, so that doesn't exist.

Comment: @juliomalves using `const {category}` did the trick. Thanks a ton. Any idea now on how can I pass this to a function for an API call?

Comment: That goes beyond the scope of this one question. I'd suggest you create a new question if you're having a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try functional component instead like below. Hooks are used in functional components.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Products = (props) => {
    const [myId, setMyId] = useState<any>(null);
    const [myCategory, setMyCategory] = useState<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.router.query)
        setMyId(props.router.query.id)
        setMyCategory(props.router.query.category)
    }, [props.router]);

    return(<h1 className="text-center">{myId}</h1>);
}
```

Alternatively

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import router from 'next/router';

const Products = () => {
    const {id, category} = router.query
    const [myId, setMyId] = useState<any>(null);
    const [myCategory, setMyCategory] = useState<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!id) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(id);
        setMyId(id);
        setMyCategory(category);
    }, [id]);
    
    return(<h1 className="text-center">{myId}</h1>);
}
```

Can you also modify your jsx a bit? For example

```
  <Link href={{
    pathname: '/products',
    query: {id: 1, category: 'Starters'}
  }}>
    Starters
  </Link>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <img class="content-image" src="/starters.png" />
        <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
          <h3 class="content-title text-uppercase">Starters</h3>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: These don't seem to be working. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The problem is that OP is trying to access `id` but `category` is what's being passed as the query parameter. See the comments on the question.

Comment: That's right, I've overlooked that. Thanks, updated.